# Where can I find viewfinder adaptions for the Fujifilm HS series?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, viewfinder, fujifilm, camera-design

For model series S/HS, in particular HS25, HS30, ...

That Fujifilm's viewfinder seems designed (misdesigned) only for persons with very wide set eyes (or with very non-prominent noses and nose bridges... Such as of Asiatic ancestry. I looked on the Fujifilm site to see if eye cups (like binoculars and such) were available. No luck. I also do not like LCD-nose interference with close-in peering into viewfinder - leaving smudge on the LCD. I think mispositioning and too short extension of the eye piece disconcerting - like reducing the camera to point by no aim - not an opinion, just an impression.

Is there a solution anyone has found that works adequately? By solution, a simple statement or link will do. Comments are okay, especially suggesting where I might collaborate to work out or design a fix gadget; but I hope not to discuss by Q&A or people get upset and tell me to FAQ.

PS: my proboscis is fairly normal, nothing overly prominent.

Comment: I am personally annoyed by viewfinders that don't naturally allow face-to-camera contact when I'm not using a tripod—I'm being deprived of considerable extra stability. Smudges can be cleaned easily in the field, especially when you compare the cleaning to, say, the effort of growing a third arm to compensate for lost support.

Comment: You clearly do not use sunscreen :) You need a wet cleaning solution to remove that stuff from LCD screens. That seriously annoys me most of those cameras with the LCD flush to the side. With other models, at least my nose rests on a row of buttons instead.

Comment: @lex - Unfortunately this is the norm on cameras below $9000 :) At least most DSLRs with a detachable eye-cup can let you substitute something but I have not seen this in fixed lens cameras.

Answer (score 1):

Many manufacturers offer viewfinder extenders, but Fuji doesn't list one among the [accessories for HS-series cameras](http://www.fujifilm.com/products/digital_cameras/s/finepix_hs50exr/accessories/). However, there are some third party "viewfinder magnifier" options that fit cameras from a number of manufacturers, including Fuji. It's hard to say whether these would fit your model (especially considering the age of this question) but they appear to move the eye cup at least a couple of centimeters farther from the back of the camera. All the models I see on Amazon look like they're the same product with different names: [Prost](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B011K7KZ0Q), [Sonovel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B017EHZNQC), [Toazoe](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B011YEASOS), and [GMYSTRIVE](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B018R5SCZY). All are priced within $0.11 of each other and cost around $26.